# HQL No data type for node exception when calling enclosed functions

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hql, h2

When I call

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery("select n.book, nvl(sum(n.val),0) from N n).list();
```

Hibernate has some trouble parsing the query and throws:

```
java.lang.Exception: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'nvl' {originalText=nvl}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'sum'
       |  \-[DOT] DotNode: 'n0_.val' {propertyName=val,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=val,path=n.val,tableAlias=n0_,className=com.myCompany.name.entity.account.N,classAlias=n}
       |     +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'n0_.id' {alias=n, className=com.myCompany.name.entity.account.N, tableAlias=n0_}
       |     \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'val' {originalText=val}
       \-[NUM_INT] LiteralNode: '0'
```

However

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery("select n.book, sum(n.val) from N n).list();
```

works fine.
I wonder if something is wrong with my 1st query syntax or Hibernate somehow doesn't support enclosed functions?

EDIT: NVL is Oracle function and we use Oracle DB in production. However I use in-memory H2 database for unit-testing. [H2 is said to support NVL as well](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#coalesce).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your are a little bit confused with SQL and HQL. HQL is not SQL. SQL supports a lot of functions but they are implementation specific. Some of them are "standard", i.e. have similar implementation in different databases.

HQL provides platform independent way to query objects from relational database and supports only very limited list of functions (`sum`, `min`, `max`, `avg`, `count`). Please see the following resource for details: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation

Try to google "sql nvl function" and see the results. This function is supported by Oracle but not supported by MySQL (for example). This means that its very difficult to make hibernate to support it. Moreover specifically to this function it IMHO it is not a good way even to try to use it. Move responsibility on replacing `null`s by other values to your entity or to your DAO layer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I should clarify my question then. Right now I'm testing code with above mentioned query that works with Oracle DB in production. For testing purposes I use in-memory H2 DB which supports nvl as well.

Comment: I see. I think that It is not enough that your DB supports certain operation. You need appropriate support of corresponding dialect implemented by Hibernate. Probably dialect for H2 does not support this function. But again, you are on the wrong way. Try to find design that allows simplify queries as much as it is possible and move logic to java code. This will help you to make code more testable, stable and portable.